# OpenCV c++ template recognition

Tags: c++, templates, opencv, matching

I have a template and I want to know if the template is present in an image.  Well I have googled a lot and came to the conclusion that I need to use `cvMatchTemplate` and `cvMinMaxLoc`.

Here is my code:

```
image = cvLoadImage("C:/images/flower.jpg",1);
templat = cvLoadImage("C:/images/flo.jpg",1);
image2=cvCreateImage( cvSize(image->width, image->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
result=cvCreateImage( cvSize(image->width, image->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
cvZero(result);
cvZero(image2);
cvCvtColor(image,image2,CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvMatchTemplate(image2, templat,result,CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

double min_val=0, max_val=0;
CvPoint min_loc, max_loc;
cvMinMaxLoc(result, &min_val, &max_val, &min_loc, &max_loc);

cvRectangle(image, max_loc, cvPoint(max_loc.x+templat->width,  
max_loc.y+templat->height), cvScalar(0), 1);

cvShowImage( "src", image );
cvShowImage( "result image", result);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

My problem is when I run the above code,a message box is displayed saying:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x747d812f in matching.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001ff6ec..
```

and in the black screen there is a message:

```
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match <image and template should have the same type> in unknown function, file..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\scr\cv\cvtempl.cpp, line 356.
```

Please note that `flower.jpg` is a coloured image and `flo.jpg` is the gray scale of that image.

Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: How do you declare `image` and `templat`? What are their types?

Comment: IplImage* templat= NULL;IplImage* image = NULL;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both `flower.jpg` and `flo.jpg` to single-channel image. Even if `flo.jpg` is grayscale, you're loading it as three-channel image. Also the `result` image should be `IPL_DEPTH_32F` instad of `IPL_DEPTH_8U`.

Here is the correct code (untested):

```
IplImage* image    = cvLoadImage("C:/images/flower.jpg", 1);
IplImage* templat  = cvLoadImage("C:/images/flo.jpg", 1);
IplImage* image2   = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width, image->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* templat2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(templat->width, templat->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 

cvCvtColor(image, image2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvCvtColor(templat, templat2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

int w = image->width - templat->width + 1;
int h = image->height - templat->height + 1;
result = cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
cvMatchTemplate(image2, templat, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

double min_val, max_val;
CvPoint min_loc, max_loc;
cvMinMaxLoc(result, &min_val, &max_val, &min_loc, &max_loc);

cvRectangle(image, max_loc, cvPoint(max_loc.x+templat->width, 
max_loc.y+templat->height), cvScalar(0), 1);

cvShowImage("src", image);
cvShowImage("result image", result);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Comment: @ bsdnoobz- hi i'm getting error at line "templat2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(template->width, template->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); " error C2059: syntax error : 'template':(

Comment: @vidzz Sorry I forgot you have to declare `IplImage* templat2;`. See my edited code.

Comment: @ bsdnoobz I had declared it but then i got the above mentioned error-

Comment: @vidzz I edited the code. It should be `templat` instead of `template`.

Comment: @ bsdnoobz -I am getting this error "error C2059: syntax error : 'template'" and when I change template to templat-I an getting: "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed." and the black screen I am getting:-OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match <image and template should have the same type> in unknown function, file..\..\..\..\ocv\opencv\scr\cv\cvtempl.cpp, line 356.

Comment: @ bsdnoobz- I shut down the program, open it and run it again and it works perfectly right- thank you dear (I have been struggling for days)-I accept your answer:) THANK YOU VERY MUCH:)

Answer (score 1):

Template matching assumes that both `image` and `template` have identical number of channels and channel depth. The simplest way to do is to load both of them in grayscale:

```
Mat I = imread("lena.png", 0);
Mat T = imread("template.png", 0);
```

Notes: I would command to use OpenCV2.0 C++ interface. So instead of `cvLoadImage` use `imread`. The old interface is no longer developed.